# Getting 302 error after submitting POST form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, post, routes

I am getting:

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

on 302 error after submitting a form.

I've tried

`php artisan route:cache`

switching between route::get and route::post

TranscationController.php

```
public function store(TransactionRequest $request)
{
   $suser = User::findOrFail($request->s_uid);
   $ruser = User::where('uid',$request->r_uid)->first();
   //...
   //...
   //...
   return redirect()->route('transfer');
}
```

web.php

```
 Route::get('/', 'HomeController@home')->name('login');
 Route::get('/contact', 'HomeController@contact')->name('contact');
 Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@home')->name('home');
 Route::get('/transfer', 'HomeController@transfer')->name('transfer');
 Route::get('/account', 'HomeController@account')->name('account');
 Route::get('/transactionHistory/{id}', 'TransactionController@show')- 
 >name('show');
 Route::post('/transactions', 'TransactionController@store')- 
 >name('store');
 //Route::resource('transaction', 'TransactionController');
 Auth::routes();
```

transfer.blade.php

```
    <form action="{{ route('store') }}" method="POST" >
      @csrf 
      <input type="text" id="UID" value="{{old('r_uid')}}"class="" 
      name="r_uid" placeholder="UID">
      <input type="number" id="amount" class="" value="{{old('amount')}}" 
      name="amount" placeholder="0.0$">
      <input type="hidden" name="s_uid" value="{{Auth::id()}}">
      <input type="submit" class="" value="Send">
    </form>
```

i also noticed if instead i use route::resource, on 302 error i dont get MethodNotAllowed error, i get redirceted to TransactionController index method

Comment: `302` is not an error, but a redirect.

Answer (score 3):

Would you please try again like this-

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('transactions', 'TransactionController');
```

**transfer.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('transactions.store') }}" method="POST" >
  @csrf 
  <input type="text" id="UID" value="{{old('r_uid')}}"class="" 
  name="r_uid" placeholder="UID">
  <input type="number" id="amount" class="" value="{{old('amount')}}" 
  name="amount" placeholder="0.0$">
  <input type="hidden" name="s_uid" value="{{Auth::id()}}">
  <input type="submit" class="" value="Send">
</form>
```

And then cache clear -

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: Nope, tried that, well i am atleast not getting the InavlidMethod error, but i still get 302

Comment: If i use only 'store' and 'show' methods which are the only ones i use, i still get the InvalidMethod error

Comment: run `php artisan route:list` from your terminal and you will find the whole route list.

Comment: Did you find the route list?

Comment: Would you please visit the laravel `resource` controller - https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#resource-controllers